# How to repair .net framework registry

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, .net-framework

I had a huge malware issue and I solved it by running the Avira Rescue System on a bootable flashdrive which luckily removed the malware but now my .NET Framework is completely broken, the registry is missing a bunch of stuff. Firstly, I get an error when trying to launch certain applications:

[image]

Attempting to reinstall the latest version gives me this:

[image]

And so I tried following the directions [here](https://www.download3k.com/articles/Fixing-Please-set-registry-key-HKLM-Software-Microsoft-.NETFramework-InstallRoot-to-point-to-the-.NET-Framework-install-location-error-on-a-64-bit-Windows-PC-01947) but when I open regedit:

[image]

My registry is missing an entire section pertaining to the .NET Framework.

[image]

*Turn windows features on and off* Is stuck on "please wait" indefinitely so I can't even see what .NET Frameworks Windows says I have installed, and yet:

[image]

I clearly have several versions of the .Net framework installed.

In Microsoft's never-ending pursuit to make their operating system as inconvenient as posible they've made it impossible for you to uninstall the .NET Framework so manual re-installation isn't possible. I've tried their .NET Framework repair wizard but that was about as useful as a screen door on a submarine. Hlp plz.

Comment: Reset your installation.  It’s hosed.  There isn’t a way to reinstall or repair .Net 4.7.2 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will solve the problem, but you could export the missing registry key from another computer, and import on the broken PC.  Additionally, you could install another windows in a VM and then grap the key.

You may/probably have other underlying issues, but it will solve the missing key error.

InstallRoot is C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\

on my PC and its probably the same for you.